# Recursive call to a rule

Tags: recursion, clips

I have this rule that fires thousands of other same rule:

```
(defrule calculate-temperature
    ?zone <- (object (is-a ZONE) (id ?id-zone) (dew-temperature ?dew-temperature) (delta-R ?delta-R))
    (process-action (is cooling))        
    =>
    (bind ?supply-temperature (+ ?delta-R ?dew-temperature))
    (modify-instance ?zone (supply-temperature ?supply-temperature))        
    (printout ?*debug-print* "supply-temperature:", ?supply-temperature crlf))
```

What I want to do is to modify my zone's supply-temperature when I can calculate it, i.e. when inside zone are defined delta-R and dew-temperature.
But the modification of the object keeps on firing in a recursice neverendless cycle.
What are best practices to avoid these annoying loops, please?

Thank you 
Nicola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By itself this rule doesn't loop:

```
CLIPS> (clear)
CLIPS> 
(defclass ZONE
   (is-a USER)
   (slot id)
   (slot dew-temperature)
   (slot supply-temperature)
   (slot delta-R))
CLIPS> 
(definstances start-instances
   (z1 of ZONE (id 1) (dew-temperature 100) (delta-R 10)))
CLIPS>    
(deftemplate process-action 
   (slot is))
CLIPS> 
(deffacts start-facts
   (process-action (is cooling)))
CLIPS> (defglobal ?*debug-print* = nil)
CLIPS> 
(defrule calculate-temperature
   ?zone <- (object (is-a ZONE) 
                    (id ?id-zone)
                    (dew-temperature ?dew-temperature)
                    (delta-R ?delta-R))
   (process-action (is cooling))        
   =>
   (bind ?supply-temperature (+ ?delta-R ?dew-temperature))
   (modify-instance ?zone (supply-temperature ?supply-temperature))        
   (printout ?*debug-print* "supply-temperature:", ?supply-temperature crlf))
CLIPS> (watch slots)
CLIPS> (reset)
::= local slot id in instance z1 <- 1
::= local slot dew-temperature in instance z1 <- 100
::= local slot delta-R in instance z1 <- 10
::= local slot supply-temperature in instance z1 <- nil
CLIPS> (run)   
::= local slot supply-temperature in instance z1 <- 110
CLIPS>
```

So it's the interactions between your rules that are causing the loop.

There are three general techniques to prevent rule looping. First, you can remove one of the facts/instances matching the conditions of the rule. For example, the process-action fact:

```
(defrule calculate-temperature
   ?zone <- (object (is-a ZONE) 
                    (id ?id-zone)
                    (dew-temperature ?dew-temperature)
                    (delta-R ?delta-R))
   ?p <- (process-action (is cooling))        
   =>
   (retract ?p)
   (bind ?supply-temperature (+ ?delta-R ?dew-temperature))
   (modify-instance ?zone (supply-temperature ?supply-temperature))        
   (printout ?*debug-print* "supply-temperature:", ?supply-temperature crlf))
```

Second, you can modify a fact/instance slot value to prevent a pattern from matching. For example, delta-R:

```
(defrule calculate-temperature
   ?zone <- (object (is-a ZONE) 
                    (id ?id-zone)
                    (dew-temperature ?dew-temperature)
                    (delta-R ?delta-R&~0))
   (process-action (is cooling))        
   =>
   (bind ?supply-temperature (+ ?delta-R ?dew-temperature))
   (modify-instance ?zone (supply-temperature ?supply-temperature) (delta-R 0))        
   (printout ?*debug-print* "supply-temperature:", ?supply-temperature crlf))
```

Third (and this is only applicable for object pattern matching), rules are only triggered by changes to slots that are explicitly matched in the conditions of the rules. So if you want changes to delta-R to trigger the rule, but not changes to dew-temperature, you'd write the rule like this:

```
(defrule calculate-temperature
   ?zone <- (object (is-a ZONE) 
                    (id ?id-zone)
                    (delta-R ?delta-R))
   (process-action (is cooling))        
   =>
   (bind ?supply-temperature (+ ?delta-R (send ?zone get-dew-temperature)))
   (modify-instance ?zone (supply-temperature ?supply-temperature))        
   (printout ?*debug-print* "supply-temperature:", ?supply-temperature crlf))
```